# astropy.table.Table.read appears to not be functioning properly for "no header" format

Tags: python, astropy

I am attempting to read in data of mixed datatypes saved to a file (here I use 'testfile.txt') with the form:

```
a,1
b,2
1.0     2.0     abc
3.0     4.0     edf
5.0     6.0     ghk
```

with the goal to access and manipulate the data at and below line 3 (e.g. plot columns, perform analysis...). I have been, for some time, doing this by using the astropy.table.Table.read function:

```
from astropy.table import Table

raw_data = Table.read(testfile.txt,format='ascii.no_header',delimiter='\t',data_start=3,guess=False)
```

This was working for some time, but now I am getting the following error:

InconsistentTableError: Number of header columns (1) inconsistent with data columns in data line 1

with the impression that this error comes from trying to read in a header (yet the format is 'no_header'). Although I don't believe much has changed since when it was working, I did upgrade astropy to version 4.0 but am doubtful that is the case. What is strange is if I use the format "ascii.fixed_width_no_header" with the same kwargs:

```
raw_data = Table.read(testfile.txt,format='ascii.fixed_width_no_header',delimiter='\t',data_start=3,guess=False)
```

The data is actually read in, without error, but my columns are not fixed width so this does not help.

Answer (score 1):

It does appear there is a bug in the C "fast reader" for the `no_header` format. I'll open an issue on that (https://github.com/astropy/astropy/issues/9797).  But the (slower) pure Python implementation works as expected by adding `fast_reader=False`:

```
>>> ascii.read(txt, format='no_header', data_start=2, guess=False, fast_reader=False)
<Table length=3>
  col1    col2  col3
float64 float64 str3
------- ------- ----
    1.0     2.0  abc
    3.0     4.0  edf
    5.0     6.0  ghk
```

Note that you could also have allowed guessing:

```
>>> ascii.read(txt, format='no_header', data_start=2)
<Table length=3>
  col1    col2  col3
float64 float64 str3
------- ------- ----
    1.0     2.0  abc
    3.0     4.0  edf
    5.0     6.0  ghk
```

Comment: Great, thanks to know it isn't something on my end. However, I am curious.. what is the point of having a 'fast_no_header' vs 'no_header' format if the fast reader can be enabled/disabled by a kwarg?